# How to add a divide line to a footer line of angular-material table

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I want a line between last row (Swimg suit) and Footer Line (Total). How can I achieve this?

I use Angular 15

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The below CSS will remove the hiding of the line of the last row!

css

```
.footer-border-needed .mdc-data-table__row:last-child .mat-mdc-cell {
  border-bottom-color: var(
    --mat-table-row-item-outline-color,
    rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12)
  ) !important;
  border-bottom-width: var(--mat-table-row-item-outline-width, 1px) !important;
  border-bottom-style: solid !important;
}
```

html

```
<table
  mat-table
  [dataSource]="dataSource"
  class="mat-elevation-z8 footer-border-needed"
>
  <!--- Note that these columns can be defined in any order.
        The actual rendered columns are set as a property on the row definition" -->

  <!-- Position Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>No.</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.position}}</td>
    <th mat-header-cell *matFooterCellDef>Symbol</th>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Name Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Name</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.name}}</td>
    <th mat-header-cell *matFooterCellDef>Symbol</th>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Weight Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Weight</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.weight}}</td>
    <th mat-header-cell *matFooterCellDef>Symbol</th>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Symbol Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Symbol</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
      <mat-form-field
        appearance="outline"
        class="no-bottom-space custom-form-field"
      >
        <mat-label>Outline form field</mat-label>
        <input matInput placeholder="Placeholder" />
      </mat-form-field>
    </td>
    <th mat-header-cell *matFooterCellDef>Symbol</th>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
  <tr mat-footer-row *matFooterRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
</table>
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/2uvqbv-xfbmht?file=src%2Fexample%2Ftable-basic-example.html,src%2Fexample%2Ftable-basic-example.ts,src%2Fstyles.scss)